# htaccess enforce "www" yet allow subdomain access

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have looked for the solution everywhere but couldn't find the exact solution I am looking for. I am not good at htaccess stuff. Need some help.

I have enforced "www" in my htaccess file and its getting on the way when I tried to create a subdomain.

I am using this setting i found and so far its working fine without subdomain.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_Host} ^(www\.)?example\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

After creating a subdomain, its addding "www" at front and getting redirected to main site instead of subdomain.

```
For example: folder.domain.com -> becomes -> www.folder.domain.com (displayes the main site)
```

What modification is needed on top of what I have in this htaccess?

1. Enforce "www".
2. Also allow subdomain if its not "www".
3. plus subdomin URL from ".net" also redirects to ".com"

By the way my main site is in codeigniter and I also have this:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|media|style)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Wanted to install blog on subfolder and use it as subdomain.

easy way was to modify (add "blog")

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|media|style|blog)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

then I an access it as www.domain.com/blog

But I wanted it neat and clean way so that controller created URL will not conflict with sub-folders. Probably not allow access subfolders directly.

Thanks

Comment: just to make sure we are clear - you want `folder.domain.com` to go through unmolested, but `domain.com` should become `www.domain.com`. Perhaps a few examples of "this becomes that" would be helpful. Is `subdomain` always the same string? That would make life easier.

Comment: @Floris: Thanks for quick response. Yes exactly. My main site is in codeigniter and now I wanted to install blog on subfolder and use it as subdomain "blog.mainsite.com"... so yes in my case subdomain is a fixed string.

Comment: So you want `folder.domain.com` to not to become `www.folder.domain.com`?

Comment: @anubhava: exactly. Also enforce the www if somebody enters pure domain (mainsite.com = www.mainsite.com) but should not modify if other subdomain is entered like "blog.mainsite.com"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mainsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_Host} ^(.+?)\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Your modification worked but its still showing main site. I guess rules of codeigniter is in action.

Comment: Can you try it out in a new browser to avoid 301 caching issues.

Comment: I have modified the codeigniter rule to       "RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|media|style)
RewriteRule ^(blog.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]"   together with your solution and it works fine now. "blog.mainsite.com" works fine. Just don't have clue on how to redirect the subdomains from ".net" to ".com" too.

Comment: I have added this line "RewriteCond %{HTTP_Host} ^(blog\.)?mainsite\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blog.mainsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]"  but when I use the URL "blog.mainsite.net" its not redirecting to "blog.mainsite.com".... Any suggestion?

Comment: check updated rule above for redirecting all sites with `.com to .net`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. Might be helpful for others too.

I did modified

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mainsite\.com$ [NC]
```

as suggested by **Anubhava**

Then changed

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(blog.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

For ".net" to ".com" subdomain redirection I added

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_Host} ^(blog\.)?mainsite\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blog.mainsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

and added the parked domain in my host.

Everything is working perfectly now.

Thanks!